# Macro VBA Help in copying specific worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new to VBA.. tried it for first time today.

I am looking for an Excel macro which copies the last two worksheets of 5 workbooks lying in a certain folder on desktop , into a new workbook named as output_DDMMYYHHMMSS.xlsx

I am able to copy all the worksheets from all the 5 workbooks to the output workbook.
Below is the code used:
Sub MergeExcelFiles()

```
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

Path = "C:\Users\se\Desktop"
outputName = "output.xlsx"

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1
            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next
            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next
        fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
        wbkCurBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: No need for using all-caps in the title.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated accordingly @chade_

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I have updated @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. Can you help on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All worksheets in a Workbook got an `Index` property. Index 1 means first sheet, index 2 second one, and so on. So the last sheet will have an Index equal to `Sheets.Count`. Knowing this, try replacing this part:

```
For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1
            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next
            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next
```

And use this code:

```
For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
             countFiles = countFiles + 1
            countSheets = wbkSrcBook.Sheets.Count 'total sheets in this workbook
            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                'last sheet got an index equal to countSheets.
                'the sheet before the last one will be then countSheets-1
                If wksCurSheet.Index = countSheets Or wksCurSheet.Index = (countSheets - 1) Then wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next
            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next
```

Also, replace line:

```
MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
```

With:

```
MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged 2 worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
```

Comment: Thanks Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: Your solution was helpful.
Can you please help with the below?

I am trying to sort certain columns of certain sheets of the final workbook.

Comment: I added the below code after the FOR loop :

Comment: For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
            If wksCurSheet.Name = "ma_SMS%" Then 
            Dim strDataRange As Range
            Dim keyRange As Range
            'Assigning the target sort Range to strDataRange
            Set strDataRange = Range("A1:S400")
            Set keyRange = Range("A1")
            'Sorting the data using range objects and Sort method
            strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes
            Next

Comment: But the above code is not helping... though the statements for sorting is right which I verified on another excel document

Comment: If my answer helped you in your first question, please, mark it as correct, so the question will be closed. And for your second question, please, do not use comments. Just open a new question and somebody will help for sure :)